# Should i develop in codeigniter now on?

Tags: php, codeigniter, frameworks, codeigniter-2

Their official site says they are willing to sell this framework, just wondering what will be the future of CI, or I should simply switch framework ?

Comment: I've used CodeIgniter for a year but IMHO, It's Laravel time.

Comment: Just use it, its cool and I don't think licensing is going to change

Comment: there are still people committing code to CI 3 so while the folks at ellislab aren't touching it, the community is, but I do understand your concerns about the stability of the frameworks future. I've switched to Laravel myself but thats more of personal choice.

Answer (score 17):

> “Oracle/Sun/whatever, the most recent change where everyone screamed
>   and cried about the death of MySQL which didn’t happen.” -Phil
>   Sturgeon Founder of PyroCMS

- CodeIgniter is one of the world’s most popular Open Source PHP frameworks
- Is the second most watched PHP project hosted at GitHub
- It has the highest number of forks of any PHP project at GitHub of all time

EllisLab has his ExpressionEngine CMS build on CodeIgniter, and I am sure that they will care for the next home of CodeIgniter. Also I see this as opportunity. I hope the transition to the new owner will be after careful consideration.

So, I don't agree with people that said "CodeIgniter is Dead". I will continue to work on CodeIgniter, and I hope that situation in CodeIgniter will improve.

**UPDATE 07 Oct 2014**

The [British Columbia Institute of Technology (BCIT)](http://www.bcit.ca/) in Vancouver, Canada is a highly regarded applied technology institute with 48,000 full and part-time students. Their impressive BCIT School of Computing and Academic Studies teaches CodeIgniter to 150 students a year. The new home of CodeIgniter is BCIT.

And that is the biggest advantage BCIT brought over other qualified candidates. If you use CodeIgniter, you will benefit directly from their stewardship. The success of their students is intrinsically tied to not just teaching, but in shaping CodeIgniter to be at the forefront of modern programming. The result for everyone using it is a solid and fresh foundation that you can count on.

Comment: I Feel like if Facebook takes over CI has they have there hiphop for best performance would be a revolution for CI,PHP moving FORWARD